# how to fix xcode warning “Expression result unused” in xcode 4 for UIActivityIndicatorView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, uiactivityindicatorview

i am getting a warning for

```
    spinner.hidesWhenStopped;
```

warning : Expression result unused

hope any one know this
Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well `hidesWhenStopped` is a property of `spinner` and you don't do anything with it. Try setting a value as in

```
spinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
```

or

```
spinner.hidesWhenStopped = NO;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to set the activity indicator to hide when stopped animating. The line `spinner.hidesWhenStopped` doesn't call the setter method. If you want to call the setter method you have to either use,

```
spinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
```

or,

```
[spinner setHidesWhenStopped:YES];
```